# Does salesforce now require a security token even if if you have whitelisted ip?

Tags: api, authentication, ip-whitelisting

It used to be that you could ditch the security token in API calls if you whitelisted an IP range for a user's profile.  I've got a new dev org (wouldn't be doing this for production orgs) and I still need my security token use the API.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I haven't seen any change, although it's been a few weeks since I've logged into a whitelisted site. SFDC official docs don't mention any changes I can find. Are you 100% sure you're coming through the whitelisted range?

Comment: I hope so, the whitelisted range is 0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255

Answer (score 2):

You cannot whitelist a range like that. SalesForce put in this block on purpose since that is essentially invalidating the whole purpose around IP restrictions.

I don't know if its actually published anywhere the max range you can whitelist in a single record but I promise you that is the issue.

Comment: They allowed it initially (whitelist 2^32-1 IP addresses), then changed it to allow 2^26-1 (67108863 addresses) to restrict people from adding the entire Internet; the new limit sets it to two C-blocks, more than some countries have allocated. Coincidentally, it now requires some 96 or so such blocks. Recently, blocks larger than this maximum legal size appear to fail, since my org even asked me to authorize my computer recently. Try setting the range to just one country worth of IP addresses.

Comment: You can still whitelist 0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255 if you do it from the profile, but you just cant do it from security controls->network access.

Comment: So if I'm hearing this right if you set whitelist a block of IPs larger than a certain size Salesforce just ignores it?